# Using dynamic CSS class name in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am using below in one of my Child component. I would like

```
{...this.props.class ? "className= 'form-control "+ this.props.class +"'": "className= 'form-control'"}
```

I am using this in Parent component like this.

```
class=""
```

I am getting `Warning: Invalid attribute name: 23` error in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`className={this.props.className? "form-control " + this.props.className: "form-control"}`

You can't use `class` as props variable.
It is included in the javascript predefined words which should not be used as variable name.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: Thanks @think-serious. Should I use `className` ?

Comment: Yes, you can use className.

Comment: `...this.props.class`, also I don't know what is this used for?  @abuabu

Comment: Thanks @think-seriuos. I am using this code now `{...this.props.cssClass ? "className= 'form-control "+ this.props.cssClass +"'": "className= 'form-control'"}` and still getting error https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3FJs.png.

Comment: Changed my answer. You would need something like that.

Comment: Thanks @think-serious. Your solution is working. Thanks.

Comment: Use template literals, its neater :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

You can have a prop named `className` in the child component and then pass `className ="my-class"` to your child.

In the child component, a [cleaner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) way of conditionally adding classes is :

`` className = {`form-control ${this.props.className || ""}`} ``

This says: if props.className is passed, add that, otherwise use empty string and form-control will always be there regardless of what is passed down from parent which seems to be your case.